# MS Access query in SSIS

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I appear to be having some difficultly with MS Access 2016 and SSIS.

I’m having to build a reporting application built over an MS Access DB. I am trying to SSIS data to create flat tables for the application to query off for performance reasons.

I noticed today that some queries/views that produce results in Access give zero results in SSIS. I feel this could be from the nasty auto generated SQL by MS Access. But is there a way to get round this issue without re-writing the sql?

I’m currently connecting to the access dB via jet 12.0 ole DB connector in SSIS. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps post the code/query that fails.

Comment: It seems to be almost any nested query that was generated by access itself. Will post when back at my machine.

Comment: This would help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783336/sql-in-access-and-sql-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: Access does not autogenerate nasty SQL. The query designer is a GUI that generates a SQL string (in the MS Access dialect), just like any other query designer does. It does not generate nested queries and no views, and it does not generate anything by itself.